# iOS bluetooth pairing with other phone programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, iphone-privateapi

I need to connect the bluetooth handset programmatically in one of my iOS projects. I do not want to go through iPhone settings to connect the bluetooth handset.

I searching in Google finely i got one link  [THIS](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/07/bluetooth-and-ios-use-bluetooth-in-your-iphone-apps/)

In this Link provide source Code .I download and then run that file .it's open simulator like this [image]

When I click scan button it showing Error "Turn Bluetooth on first" and then I pressed Bluetooth on button no use. 
Any Bluetooth Device are not showing.
SO please give me any idea about HOW to Connected iPhone Bluetooth pairing with other Phones Bluetooth Programmatically.

First tell me it's possible in simulator or not?

Comment: You cannot use bluetooth in the simulator, only on a real device and you cannot control the bluetooth power status or pairing from an app on a non-jail broken device. You can have two iOS devices communicate via BLE from an app but if you specify encryption which requires pairing then the user will need to complete the pairing process

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for reply i need iPhone Bluetooth connected with other phone Bluetooth like (Android) through  Pragmatically it's possible or not Please help me

Comment: There are plenty of examples on using Corebluetooth if you search.

Comment: @PavanAlapati have you got any solution from this Tutorial? I am also working on Core Bluetooth. If you have any link or idea then please share with me.